# passing context to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

well i am doing a small android project involving fragments.. my log cat is showing null pointer exception as context value is null..

this is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.syllabusselection, container, false);
    main(rootView);
    return rootView;
}
public void main(View rootView)
 {
     TextView textyear,textsubject,textschema,textPowered ;
        final Context context = getActivity();
        Typeface Roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        Typeface Nexa = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/nexa/Nexa_Light.ttf");//Nexa_Light.ttf Nexa_Bold.ttf


        textsubject = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textsubject);
        textschema = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textscheme);
        textPowered = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textPowered);
```

well originally the

final Context context = getActivity();

was null i changed it to getActivity() but still i am getting null pointer excewption.. so what is the errror??

this is my log cat

```
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218): Process: info.androidhive.tabsswipe, PID: 1218
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Question.main(Question.java:63)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Question.onCreateView(Question.java:55)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
03-10 03:30:06.015: E/AndroidRuntime(1218):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your invocation of `main` to `onActivityCreated` of the fragment. That means you should move the `rootView.findViewById` calls to `onCreateView` and retain the `Typeface` calls in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you try to get context, fragment is not attached to Activity yet. So you should rethink app logic. As pointed by @Vino you should use another callback.